# Delete row from tableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

I am a bit lost on what should be a simple action of deleting a row from a tableview.  I have an sqlite database with a  table called SUBJECT and I want to delete a record for this table, delete the member from the array and delete the entry in the tableview.  I don't know what sequence is best and I keep getting errors.

Here is the code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tv commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if(editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {

        QuotesAppDelegate *appDelegate = (QuotesAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

        //Get the object to delete from the array.
        Subject *sub = [self.subjects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        // check if there are any quoteMaps for this subject and if so do not do it

        NSArray *qm = [appDelegate getQuoteMapsFromSubId:sub.subject_id];

        if (qm.count==0){

            //Delete the object from the table.
            [self.subjects removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            [tv deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            [sub deleteSubject];


        } else {
            //DON'T DO IT BUT GIVE A WARNING INSTEAD

        }
    }
}
```

I get the following error on the self.subjects removeObject.... line:

```
-[__NSArrayI removeObjectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6b2a8f0
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 
'-[__NSArrayI removeObjectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6b2a8f0'
```

The error message says my self.subjects is an NSArray yet my header assigns it as NSMutableArray:

```
@interface SubjectViewController : UITableViewController <UIAlertViewDelegate>  {

    NSMutableArray *subjects;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *subjects;
```

Why is it changing to NSArray???

I checked and found that the Parent ViewController is assigning the following:

```
NSPredicate *catFilter = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"category_title == %@", cat.category_title];

NSArray *subs = [appDelegate.subjects filteredArrayUsingPredicate:catFilter];
 subViewController.subjects = (NSMutableArray *) subs;
```

Looks like the problem is there.

I get the following error if I comment out the self.subjects removeObject and try to run the next line of "tv deleteRowsAtIndexPaths...":

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', 
reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows
contained in an existing section after the update (1) must be equal to the number 
of rows contained in that section before the update (1), plus or minus the number 
of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 1 deleted) and plus or 
minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'
```

So far this was narrowed down to being a problem in the prior controller view where I am using an NSArray out of a NSPredicate because I couldn't get NSPredicate to work with NSMutableArray.  So now that is the issue trying to be resolved.

Or converting/assigning an NSArray as an NSMutableArray...

Comment: Where's the code where you actually create the `subjects` array?

Comment: Where do you allocate the object assigned to subjects? You must make sure to create an NSMutableArray instance; declaring the type in your header won't guarantee the type of the object assigned to it.

Comment: That's my problem.  I don't allocate it anywhere so it gets whatever default is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

NSArrays are inmmutable, that means you can't add or remove elements, hence your object doesn't have a `removeObjectAtIndex:` method.

- Check your property to see if its an `NSArray` instead of an `NSMutableArray`.
- Check that the object in that pointer is in fact an `NSMutableArray`.
- To assign an `NSArray` to your variable first create an `NSMutableArray` from it using the `arrayWithArray:` method.

Comment: Yeah I knew it was something simple like that.  Let me try.  Thanks.

Comment: But the self.subjects array is supposed to be NSMutableArray.  Somewhere it is getting changed.  I posted the header above.

Comment: @jroyce Ok I saw your entire class, where exactly did you assicn values to  subjects cause there is not a single match for subjects = <something>, check that the object you are assigning to this poiter is an NSMutableArray

Comment: Here are all the places I assign values to subjects:                 NSPredicate *catFilter = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"category_title == %@", cat.category_title];
        
    NSArray *subs = [appDelegate.subjects filteredArrayUsingPredicate:catFilter];
     subViewController.subjects = (NSMutableArray *) subs;
Looks like the problem is there.

Comment: yep, objects are not primitives, not because you 'cast' (NSArray*) the object would bend to your will and become anything you want, use the popular subjects = [NSMutableString arrayWithArray:subs];

Comment: The problem is that I couldn't get NSPredicate to work with an NSMutableArray.  Is there a way to change a NSArray to an NSMutableArray... I'll check the docs

Comment: Tried subjects = [NSMutableString arrayWithArray:subs]; but I get class method arrayWithArray not found... :(

Answer (score 2):

first your subjects array is immutable. use NSMutableArray class for subject array.

also try to use `beginUpdates` - `endUpdates` block...

```
[tv beginUpdates];
[tv deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
[tv endUpdates];
```

Comment: I updated the above post as my subjects array is set as NSMutableArray and I don't know why it is changing to NSArray...

Comment: you have to search deeply in your code. where is your allocation method? Did you write `self.subjects = [[[NSArray alloc]init]autorelease];` or `self.subjects = [NSArray array];` something like that?

Comment: I posted the entire class.  I don't think I am initializing the array anywhere... not sure if that is a problem :)

Comment: have you assign your subjects array outside of this class. you are not allocating anything in this class

Comment: I initialize the subjects array in another class here:   subjects = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

Comment: Does the TableView contain data? Does it show what it is supposed to show? If yes then subjects is initialized somewhere. Where do you present the SubjectViewController ? Post the code you use to present SubjectViewController.

Comment: I posted this above.  I found the problem area, which is in the parentViewController where I use an NSPredicate which I could only get working with an NSArray.  Now I am trying to figure out how to get that converted back to NSMutableArray before I assign it to subjects.... errrrggggh

Comment: Use [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:anArray] or [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:anArray]

Answer (score 2):

The error is being generated because your datasource, always has to be consistent with the rows added/deleted, which means if the previous call to the method:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

Returned x, and you deleted n rows, then the next call to the method after the delete animation MUST return (x-n)

Additionally if you are using an `NSArray` as your datasource and you will be adding/deleting rows then it MUST be immutable, as you have to keep your Array consistent with the adding/deletion. Therefore you need to use `NSMutableArray`.